# Show/Hide sections of text individually when button is toggled

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this show/hide toggle button working to my liking.

I also managed to get the image icon - eye to change (open and close) when I toggle between hide/show details.

You see...? I have the value attribute of the button changing as I toggle the button itself.

Now, I have two different sections of text. I would like to toggle hide/show these sections of text individually.
BUT, when I toggle to 'hide' the text in brief -II, text in brief - I is hidden! yuck!
I tried giving them different ids and incorporated the changed ids into the script. It just doesn't work! HELP!

You could also [fiddle with my codepen.](https://codepen.io/headofclowns/pen/KKVOjZE) The issue I need help with is detailed there too.

```
<body>
  <h1>So many problems to solve</h1>
  
<div class="spec-proj-briefshowhide">
  <h2>Hello! this is the first problem. This is just the beginning to an unending greed.</h2>
 <div class="showhide-buttons-icons">
    <p><img id="opencloseeye" src="https://i.ibb.co/NjRDMFS/OPENEYE.png">
  <input type="button" value="Hide details" id="bt" onclick="toggle(this); changeImage();"></p>
</div>
<div style="display:flex;" id="proj-details">
<div class="smodpvproject-brief">
 <p>Brief - I:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>So I have this show/hide toggle button working to my liking.</li>
    <li>I also managed to get the eye to open and close when I toggle between hide/show details.</li>
    <li>You see..? I have the value attribute of the button changing as I click on it to toggle too.</li>
    <li>Now, I have two different sections of text. I would like to toggle hide/show these sections of text individually.</li>
    <li>For now, even if I toggle to hide the text for brief -II, text for brief - I is hidden.</li>
    <li>I tried giving them different ids and to incorporate it into the script. It just doesnt work for me.</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<h2>Here comes the second issue of the evil eye and the sleepy eye.</h2>
  <div class="spec-proj-briefshowhide">
 <div class="showhide-buttons-icons">
    <p><img id="opencloseeye" src="https://i.ibb.co/NjRDMFS/OPENEYE.png">
  <input type="button" value="Hide details" id="bt" onclick="toggle(this); changeImage();"></p>
</div>
<div style="display:flex;" id="proj-details">
<div class="smodpvproject-brief">
 <p>Brief - II:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>The second issue is to incorporate the toggle feature to the eye(s).</li>
    <li>So when I click an open eye, I would like it to hide the text details and, simultaneously change the value of the adjacent button to 'Show details'.</li>
    <li>This should occur individually and for each section of text (meaning individually and seperately for Brief - I and Brief - II).</li>
    <li>I have a feeling that this would make it easy for people to visually recognise if the text is hidden or open.</li>
    <li>This hide/Show drama is to just save on screen real estate.</li>
    <li>Help needed!</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
  
</body>
```

```
body{
  margin:3em;
  background: #262626;
  color: #f7f7f2;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size:0.8em;
  line-height:2;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.spec-proj-briefshowhide {
           display: flex;
           flex-direction: column;
           justify-content: center;
           align-items: center;
           padding-left: 3em;
           padding-right: 3em;
  border-bottom: 0.05em solid #f7f7f2;
       }



       .spec-proj-briefshowhide input {
           padding: 0.5em;
           color: #01BAEF;
           font-size: 0.8em;
           font-weight: 400;
           text-transform: uppercase;
           cursor: pointer;
           background-color: #262626;
           border: 0.05em solid #01BAEF;
           border-radius: 0.1em;
           outline: none;
       }


       .showhide-buttons-icons img {
           max-width: 3em;
           vertical-align: middle;
           padding-left: 2em;
           padding-right: 2em;
           align-self: flex-start;
       }
```

```
function toggle(ele) {
            var cont = document.getElementById('proj-details');
            if (cont.style.display == 'flex') {
                cont.style.display = 'none';

                document.getElementById(ele.id).value = 'Show details';
            } else {
                cont.style.display = 'flex';
                document.getElementById(ele.id).value = 'Hide details';
            }
        }

function changeImage() {
            var image = document.getElementById('opencloseeye');
            if (image.src.match("https://i.ibb.co/NjRDMFS/OPENEYE.png")) {
                image.src = "https://i.ibb.co/yPhD6HF/CLOSEEYE.png";
            } else {
                image.src = "https://i.ibb.co/NjRDMFS/OPENEYE.png";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you use 'id' but it's not suitable for multiple elements because it should be unique, so just replace it with classes and also target elements in function relative to an element which you click (where you have a click handler).

Just added some correction to your [example](https://codepen.io/mazdok/pen/KKzPjGb?editors=1010);

```
<body>
  <h1>So many problems to solve</h1>

  <div class="spec-proj-briefshowhide">
    <h2>Hello! this is the first problem. This is just the beginning to an unending greed.</h2>
    <div class="showhide-buttons-icons">
      <p><img class="opencloseeye" src="https://i.ibb.co/NjRDMFS/OPENEYE.png">
        <input type="button" value="Hide details" class="bt" onclick="toggle(this); changeImage(this);"></p>
    </div>
    <div style="display:flex;" class="proj-details">
      <div class="smodpvproject-brief">
        <p>Brief - I:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>So I have this show/hide toggle button working to my liking.</li>
          <li>I also managed to get the eye to open and close when I toggle between hide/show details.</li>
          <li>You see..? I have the value attribute of the button changing as I click on it to toggle too.</li>
          <li>Now, I have two different sections of text. I would like to toggle hide/show these sections of text individually.</li>
          <li>For now, even if I toggle to hide the text for brief -II, text for brief - I is hidden.</li>
          <li>I tried giving them different ids and to incorporate it into the script. It just doesnt work for me.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <h2>Here comes the second issue of the evil eye and the sleepy eye.</h2>
  <div class="spec-proj-briefshowhide">
    <div class="showhide-buttons-icons">
      <p>
        <img class="opencloseeye" src="https://i.ibb.co/NjRDMFS/OPENEYE.png">
        <input type="button" value="Hide details" class="bt" onclick="toggle(this); changeImage(this);">
     </p>
    </div>
    <div style="display:flex;" class="proj-details">
      <div class="smodpvproject-brief">
        <p>Brief - II:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>The second issue is to incorporate the toggle feature to the eye(s).</li>
          <li>So when I click an open eye, I would like it to hide the text details and, simultaneously change the value of the adjacent button to 'Show details'.</li>
          <li>This should occur individually and for each section of text (meaning individually and seperately for Brief - I and Brief - II).</li>
          <li>I have a feeling that this would make it easy for people to visually recognise if the text is hidden or open.</li>
          <li>This hide/Show drama is to just save on screen real estate.</li>
          <li>Help needed!</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

 <script>
function toggle(el) {
  // you need to find an '.proj-details' block relatively to a 'this' element (to button)
  const cont = el.parentNode.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
  
  if (cont.style.display == "flex") {
    cont.style.display = "none";
    // you already have a current element which is passed in a function, so you can just change a value
    el.value = "Show details"
  } else {
    cont.style.display = "flex";
    el.value = "Hide details"
  }
}

function changeImage(el) {
  // save here, relative to an element which you click
  const image = el.previousElementSibling;
  
  if (image.src.match("https://i.ibb.co/NjRDMFS/OPENEYE.png")) {
    image.src = "https://i.ibb.co/yPhD6HF/CLOSEEYE.png";
  } else {
    image.src = "https://i.ibb.co/NjRDMFS/OPENEYE.png";
  }
}
 </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for commenting in line with the code and explaining each line. It helps a beginner like me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`id` should be unique in the same HTML doc, or they should be specified in a `class` if you are reusing the same 'name'.

for the above, the easiest fix is to give your briefs different ids and then pass in the id in the toggle function for it to be toggled.

i.e.
you have two sections of id `proj-details-1` and `proj-details-2` in your HTML.

Then for your toggle, you could pass in the id that needs to be toggled. `... onclick="toggle(this, 'proj-details-1'); ..."`. The other button will have a different id.

In your toggle function:

```js
function toggle(ele, projId) {
  var cont = document.getElementById(projId);
  ....
}
```

Other ways to do this could be traversing the DOM to look at sibling nodes, but the above will do what you need.

Comment: Tried this... https://jsfiddle.net/sk7n34ap/ Does not toggle at all. I am looking into it, but havent figured out where I went wrong!

Comment: you almost got it. Here's an updated version of your original code: https://jsfiddle.net/chienleng/oh2mv70a/8/